# Controlling Multiple command prompt through one main window

Tags: command-line, batch-file, logcat

Does anyone knows how to control many command prompt windows through one . What exactly I would like to do is start many command windows and then run multiple commands in all of them through a batch file. Such as starting adb shell logcat in one, kmsg in one and if kmsg stops then turn red, and similar things. 
For that I need to be able to listen to events from other command lines and also send commands to many command prompt one after the other. 
Thanks your reply is appreciated. 
If you know how to do it in perl that would also work. Plzz help!!

Comment: Not possible in batch. You can start new `CMD` instances (with or without running a program in them), and you can kill `CMD` processes. But that's where control ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated;** 
*Update Notes:*

> Took note of Jeb's suggestion and took his advice as well as Endoro's

Okay, this will be a little complicated because it needs batch files to write into some sort of file and another batch file getting / grabbing the data from said file. In order to do this, we must produce the "sender / terminal / MAIN window" for your batch file;

The script i am writing for you as of now can only support 4 Batch files being controlled by a mother batch file.

```
@echo off
:a
title Main Terminal
echo ---------------------------
set /p prompt1="Command 1: "
set /p prompt2="Command 1: "
set /p prompt3="Command 1: "
set /p prompt4="Command 1: "
if defined prompt echo %prompt% > com1.rsm
if defined prompt2 echo %prompt2% > com2.rsm
if defined prompt3 echo %prompt3% > com3.rsm
if defined prompt4 echo %prompt4% > com4.rsm
:: .RSM file extension means ReSource Module; I made it myself :3
goto a
```

Receiver

```
@echo off
title Reciever 1
:check
if EXIST com1.rsm goto get
timeout /t 1 >nul
echo Waiting for packet
goto check
:get
set /p prompt1=<com1.rsm
%prompt1%
del com1.rsm
goto check
```

Receiver 2

```
@echo off
title Reciever 2
:check
if EXIST com2.rsm goto get
timeout /t 1 >nul
echo Waiting for packet
goto check
:get
set /p prompt=<com2.rsm
%prompt%
del com1.rsm
goto check
```

Receiver 3

```
@echo off
title Reciever 3
:check
if EXIST com3.rsm goto get
timeout /t 1 >nul
echo Waiting for packet
goto check
:get
set /p prompt=<com3.rsm
%prompt%
del com1.rsm
goto check
```

Receiver 4

```
@echo off
title Reciever 4
:check
if EXIST com4.rsm goto get
timeout /t 1 >nul
echo Waiting for packet
goto check
:get
set /p prompt=<com4.rsm
%prompt%
del com1.rsm
goto check
```

You're welcome;
SonorousTwo

Comment: Same goes with `if NOT defined` ?

Comment: +1 Good idea, but to use `prompt` as variable isn't, as prompt is reserved for the prompt format. Btw. You don't need four different receivers, a single one would work with a parameter to configure it

Comment: The poster, however, is asking to control multiple batch files; the receivers are practically the batch files.